# How do I know the Timeout specified by the client on the server side

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I want to know the timeout specified by the client on the server side (ASP.NET Web API),

This is required as on the server side I further make an HTTP calls to external services and I want to propagate the timeout specified at the client.

Is this possible?

Comment: Pass the timeout as a parameter.